# Old questions from people with 1 reputation point

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Should there be a time limit for old questions from users with very low reputation? It seems that some of the stale questions are from users that will never return. Perhaps there should be a limit set to the number of days that a question asked by a first-timer will remain before it is automatically flagged or removed.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but why should we care about who asked a question? If it is a good question, it stays, else it is closed/removed, independently from who asked it (at least in theory, practice has its exceptions unfortunately) or how long they participate.

Answer (score 10):

This already happens, but it's not based on the reputation of the user: it's based on the score (votes) of the question, the number of views, and a couple of other things. Questions with helpful answers also won't be deleted.

The network-wide meta site has [a description of when questions get automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/222389). The system is known as *Roomba*.